# Inertia moment: column vectors and products

Tags: matrices, inner-products, cross-product

$ r×(\omega×r)=(r\cdot r)\omega - (r\cdot \omega)r = |r|^2\omega - (r\cdot \omega)r = ???? = (|r|^2 I_{3\times 3} - r r^T)\omega$

These are all column vectors while $I_{3\times 3}$ is an identity matrix and $r^T$ is a row vector.

This is a step needed to prove the matrix form of the moment of inertia used here:

[https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/waveguide/Angular_Momentum_Vector_Matrix.html](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Ejos/waveguide/Angular_Momentum_Vector_Matrix.html)

I am interested in the mathematical steps required in the ???? symbols.

I don't understand where comes from the 3×3 identity matrix called "I" .

Here:

$\cdot$  means "dot product";

$\times$ means "cross product".

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ES6gu.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: All you need to check is that $rr^\top$ is the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product)
$$
\begin{pmatrix}r_1r_1&r_1r_2&r_1r_3\\r_1r_2&r_2r_2&r_2r_3\\r_1r_3&r_2r_3&r_3r_3\end{pmatrix}
$$
and that (in your notation) $(r\bullet \omega)r$ equals $(rr^\top)\omega$.

Comment: Maybe you should start from the right-hand side and unpack the notation.  Good luck!